# eclipse can not recognise my layout folder

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

eclipse can not recognise my layout folder, my layouts could not be referenced by

```
R.layout.activity_qr01
```

and the error says:my layout can not be resolved or is not a field

the code of activity_qr01 is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".QR01" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please upload the code of `activity_qr01.xml` file.

Comment: i posted the code the activity_qr01

Comment: can i post an answer to my question or it is not allowed

Comment: Yes you can answer your own question, it is fairly allowed :)

Answer (score 2):

Your XML file is in the `res/menu` folder, it should be in the `res/layout` folder.

Comment: my layout folder is inside the res folder

Comment: D:\workspaceQR\QR01\res\menu\activity_qr01.xml

No, it is not.

Comment: i found the same xml file activity_qr01 inside the menue folder and now i deleted it and i have only on activity_qr01 inside the res folder and the problem still exist and consol does not display any errors but the activity_qr01 still unrecognised

Comment: i found the solutionwhich is: i had to remove the import andrid.R and replace it by the package name .R i.e: import com.example.qr01.R;

Comment: can i post an answer to my question or it is not allowed

Comment: This should be the answer. He pointed out that your xml was in res/menu. I think after deleting it all you needed to do was to clean your project and run..

Comment: @Amr, yes, you can post your own answer and accept it. Next time double check the error message and be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `</RelativeLayout>` at the end.

Also, your file is called `activity_qr01.xml`, so you must reference it as `R.layout.activity_qr01`

Comment: i referenced R.layout.activity_qr01, what i posted is just an example

Comment: can i post an answer to my question or it is not allowed

Comment: It's allowed and you're actually encouraged to do so.